# fbDidLogin not called in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, opengl-es

I have an iPhone app and I can log in through Facebook via safari and then it redirects back to my app but fbDidLogin is not called and fbDidNotLogin is not called.

I can detect when my app gets focus back but m_pFacebook.accessToken is still null at that time.

I can't alter Facebook.m because I don't have one. My project is using the Facebook static library and I'm not totally sure what that means it looks like we use Facebook.h but not Facebook.m

```
- (void)attempt
{
m_pFacebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];

    if (![m_pFacebook isSessionValid])
    {
        NSLog( @"\nFacebook session is not valid" );

        [m_pFacebook authorize:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"\nFacebook session is valid" );
    }

}

// Pre iOS 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSLog( @"\nhandleOpenURL:%@", url );
    return [m_pFacebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

// For iOS 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog( @"\nopenURL:%@", url );
    return [m_pFacebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}



- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSLog(@"\nFacebook Did Log In");
    NSLog(@"\nAccess Token is %@", m_pFacebook.accessToken );
    NSLog(@"\nExpiration Date is %@", m_pFacebook.expirationDate );
}

- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
{
    NSLog(@"\n Facebook Failed to log in");
}
```

Comment: I've already implemented handleOpenURL, per the code I posted

Comment: I don't have a UIViewController because my app is a openGL app.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure your view controller conforms to the `<FBRequestDelegate>` protocol.